# How to access .Net MVC4 Mobile application through Iphone?

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net-mvc-4

I have started learning MVC4, and working on simple mobile site, but I am wondering how to open that a site through iPhone. Could anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean: How do I test my MVC4 application on the IPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your project in Visual Studio's, in the solution explorer right click on your solution and select "Enable IIS Express". This will make sure you are using IIS Express to test your project. Then run your app to make sure it comes up in your browser like it did before, `http://localhost:2121`

Now, in Windows, go to Documents or My Documents, and you should see a directory called `IISExpress`. Inside this there is a directory called `Config`. Inside `Config` open the file `applicationhost.config`. This contains the settings for every project that is run on IIS Express.

Scroll down till you find your site inside the `<sites>` section. It will look something like this:

```xml
<sites>
        <site name="WebSite1" id="1">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2121:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
</sites>
```

Remove the `localhost` from the `bindingInformation` so it will look like this:

```xml
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2121:" />
```

Now save the file, and restart IIS Express. The easiest way is to just restart Visual Studios.

Make sure Windows or any firewall/anti-virus programs are not blocking the port of your web application, in my example it was `2121`, and you should be good to go.

What we did was to tell IIS Express that any connection to this port is to go to this site/application. So if you setup your router to forward the port to your development computer you/anyone can access your site as long as your working on it from your development system. This is nice when you make changes and just want to check with someone outside you LAN without having to deploy the site.

So now you can access the application/site from your IPhone or any other device while it is running on your development system. If your IPhone is not connected in your local area network, you will need to add the port to the port forwarding on your router as I mentioned above then access your site by your IP address colon port number. You can also add a sub-domain to a website you own (or a free online DNS system) so you can access your dev application/site by going to `http://dev.somedomain.com:2121`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to test the site you are developing is finding out your local IP and configuring your IIS to serve your development site from that IP.

Answer (score 0):

looks little bit late anyways for other peoples. we can use iis express web server to view site from remote here is [Accessing local sites from Lan IIS Express](http://www.codeplussoft.com/Pages/siteonlan) step by step guide for this problem hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio's built-in "Web Development Server" does not allow remote connections.  You will need to host your application on IIS to be able to access the site from another computer or your iPhone.